# If a horizontally distributed database loses a shard, what happens to that shard's data?

Tags: database, sharding

In the concept of a horizontally distributed database, what happens when a shard becomes unavailable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question is pretty vague. In databases where you can control the replication factor and the consistency level like [Cassandra](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ArchitectureOverview) or [Voldemort](http://project-voldemort.com/) your data should be safe (unless you mess with it).

In the other hand (but I wouldn't call them horizontally distributed database) there are projects like memcached or redis where each shards handles a given set of data (one copy only). So in case some shard goes down that dataset will be lost (unless you use replication, or something like that...) but certainly there is not redundancy of the data in the cluster it self